# Sending an email from mySQL Store Procedure

Tags: mysql, events, email, stored-procedures, smtp

Can I write a Stored Procedure (or a simple query) in mySQL which can send an email out containing results of a query.

Any help will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Not without modifications. It has no email-related functions at all. You could write a custom module for it to add such a function, but it seems to me that something like that is in the purview of the application using MySQL, not MySQL itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly in MySQL, but I worked on something similar over the weekend.

**Background:** I wrote an app over the weekend to learn PHP. I knew I would have to be emailing out information from a MySQL database, so I needed a way to send emails with PHP easily, so I integrated [PostageApp](http://www.postageapp.com/) into my app, which took less than 15 minutes.

**Relevant:** I wrote a script to pull specific rows in MySQL, and used `mysql_fetch_array()` to be able to access the information for each of the fields in a row. With the array, I just passed the variables into a PostageApp API call, which used a template that had placeholders for these variables. PostageApp did the rest for me.

Here's how my template in PostageApp looked like:

```
Hey {{first_name}},

On {{date}}, we noted that you went to {{url}} for the first time.
```

Of course, not exactly what it is, but those are the variables, that were then passed into the API call.

Let me know if I can help you out with that.

(**Full Disclosure:** I am the Product Manager of PostageApp. But I actually did build an app over the weekend as a side project.)